# How to align colons in LaTeX?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have the following two sentences:

```
Programming Languages: C/C++, Python, Haskell
Spoken Languages: English, French
```

I would like the colons to be aligned such that they look like this:

```
Programming Languages: C/C++, Python, Haskell
Spoken Languages:      English, French
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use a `description` environment/list?

Comment: How can I do that? I am new to LaTeX, sorry.

Comment: `\begin{description}\item[Programming Languages:] ... \item[Spoken Languages: ...\end{description}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a `tabular` environment?

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
Programming Languages & C/C++, Python, Haskell\\
Spoken Languages      & English, French
\end{tabular}
```